# Unity 2D - How to make Resolution-Independent colliders on my sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, screen-resolution

I'm currently working on a school project where we have to merge a 2010 game with an arcade-style game. I chose to merge COD:Blackops Zombie mode with Pacman.

Right off the bat I'm having issues. I'm trying to figure out how I can make the colliders for my level scale with the resolution.

I have an orthographic camera that has a size of 5.

This is what my level currently looks like.
[image: image showing colliders are in place]

As you can see above, the level itself is a single sprite, placed in a canvas that has Scale with Screen Size enabled.
I've placed a couple of 2D colliders on empty game objects on it for testing purposes. 
The current resolution is 1920x1080, which is a 16:9 aspect ratio.

However, if I change the resolution to something like 800x600, which is a 4:3 aspect ratio... then the colliders are completely wrong now.
[image: image showing colliders are not place]

I thought that the colliders would scale with screen size just like the level sprite does, but I was wrong.

I am now trying to find an alternative approach to making the level have colliders that also change with the size of the sprite...

If you need more information please let me know and I will gladly update my question with the requested information.

Comment: it doesnt work because colliders live in world space, not screen/viewport space as the UI does (unless its on a "special form of canvas", but that wouldnt scale either). you either find a different (self-made?) solution for collisions on the UI or create your game in the world and reposition your camera accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, first start with a square aspect canvas.
Make an Empty GameObject, and place it at the bottom left corner of your canvas.

Put all your colliders inside this empty GameObject, and set them up so they match your play-field.

Now all you'll need to do is have a script on this empty gameobject that sets in Update():

```
Vector2 screenScale = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height).normalized;
transform.localScale = new Vector3(screenScale.x, screenScale.y, 1);
```

This will make it scale everything inside it to the same proportions as the screen. Alternatively, you could use the Canvas's size if you want to make it based on that instead of the screen itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try this next time I get the chance to and I'll let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. My teacher recommended that I stick to one aspect ratio instead of trying to scale, as I'd be spending too much time trying to figure it out. However I would love to learn how to do it anyways for the future!

Here's a video of me going through your proposed solution. :) 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESGYejuOoP4&feature=youtu.be

Maybe I made a mistake?

Comment: Nah you didn't make a mistake, there's just a bit more to getting it to work because of how the canvas element plays into scaling the children as well. I don't have much time to debug it right now but the idea is sound, just have to counteract those quirks. I might come back to this later if you don't manage to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Well, since my teacher recommended that I stick to one aspect ratio, that's what I'm currently doing. That way I can actually finish my school project in time instead of still being on step one haha...